# Java: Why is the integer in the main method combined with method

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main_5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         int m = sc.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
            String password = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(got(password));
        }
    }

    public static String got(String password) {
        HashMap<Character, Integer> checkpass = new HashMap<>();
        Character ch = null;
        Integer val = 0;
        int odd = 0, even = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
            ch = password.charAt(i);
            if (checkpass.containsKey(ch) == false) {
                checkpass.put(ch, 1);
            } else {
                 val = (Integer) checkpass.get(ch);
                checkpass.put(ch, val + 1);
            }
         }
         Set<Character> hashval = checkpass.keySet();
        for (Character key : hashval) {
             val = (Integer) checkpass.get(key);
            if (val == password.length())
                return "YES";
            else if (val % 2 == 1)
                odd++;
            else
                even++;
        }
        if (odd == 1 || odd == 0)
            return "YES";
        else
            return "NO";
    }

}
```

*PLEASE TEST THIS OUT FOR YOURSELF* 
As you can see, there is integer m in the main method. When I hit run, it makes integer m as if it were part of the got method. This is a code to find if x Strings can be a permutation palindrome.
This should what the console should look like:

```
*Input*:
     3
     ccaabcbb
     azzza
     bbbbccccdddddddd
*Output*:
     NO
     YES
     YES
```

Comment: How would i fix it?

Comment: Because, i want to make the     'String password = sc.nextLine();

Comment: run m amount of times and  System.out.println(got(password)); print out m amount of times based on the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sc.next() instead sc.nextLine() as its giving the empty line created by your first enter.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main_5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         int m = sc.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
            String password = sc.next();
            System.out.println(got(password));
        }
    }

    public static String got(String password) {
        HashMap<Character, Integer> checkpass = new HashMap<>();
        Character ch = null;
        Integer val = 0;
        int odd = 0, even = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
            ch = password.charAt(i);
            if (checkpass.containsKey(ch) == false) {
                checkpass.put(ch, 1);
            } else {
                 val = (Integer) checkpass.get(ch);
                checkpass.put(ch, val + 1);
            }
         }
         Set<Character> hashval = checkpass.keySet();
        for (Character key : hashval) {
             val = (Integer) checkpass.get(key);
            if (val == password.length())
                return "YES";
            else if (val % 2 == 1)
                odd++;
            else
                even++;
        }
        if (odd == 1 || odd == 0)
            return "YES";
        else
            return "NO";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I my be wrong, but rewritting getting `m` to this:

```
int m = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
```

should do the trick. There is problem using scanner's `nextInt()` and reading new line from standard input.